Tidy/fable way to select many exogenous regressors from a data.frame?
Q: What is the tidy / tidyverts / fable way of selecting many exogenous regressors from a data.frame for use in model fitting, esp., with ARIMA()? 
I set up a minimal working example below. You can see from my many failed attempts that I'm struggling to understand the rlang world of defusions, symbolisations, injections, splicing, etc. But I think I landed on approach at the very end which might be the tidy way: dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(!!!xreg.syms))).
Even if that is right, why? I'm asking because I'm not quite sure why that worked and why my other attempts failed.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)

set.seed(123)

tibble(
  idx=1:12,
  y=rnorm(12),
  x1=c(0,0,1,rep(0,9)),
  x2=c(rep(0,9),1,0,0)) %>%
  tsibble(index=idx) -> 
  dat
# # A tsibble: 12 x 4 [1]
# idx       y    x1    x2
# <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 -0.560      0     0
# 2     2 -0.230      0     0
# 3     3  1.56       1     0
# 4     4  0.0705     0     0
# 5     5  0.129      0     0
# 6     6  1.72       0     0
# 7     7  0.461      0     0
# 8     8 -1.27       0     0
# 9     9 -0.687      0     0
# 10    10 -0.446      0     1
# 11    11  1.22       0     0
# 12    12  0.360      0     0

# summing?
# this works, but I have many x, and don't want to write these all out
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1+x2)) # SUCCESS

# tidyselect?
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1:x2)) # FAILURE

# with xreg()?
# works but, again, I don't want to write these out individually
# still, passing to xreg() might be the way
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(x1,x2))) # SUCCESS

# char vector?
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-idx, -y) %>% colnames() -> xreg.ch
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(xreg.ch))) # FAILURE

# list?
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-idx, -y) %>% colnames() %>% as.list() -> xreg.ls
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(xreg.ls))) # FAILURE

# dataframe?
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-idx, -y) -> xreg.df 
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(xreg.df))) # FAILURE

# char vector, but unsplice with `!!!` splice operator?
# Error says
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(!!!xreg.ch))) # FAILURE
# Error says `ARIMA(y ~ xreg("x1", "x2")) [1] invalid model formula in ExtractVars`
# Suggests I may need to use expr(), as.formula(), sym(), or something of the like

# with vars()?
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(vars(x1,x2)))) # FAIL

# with a matrix?
# succeeds, but is a little ugly, I suspect there's a tidier way
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-idx, -y) %>% as.matrix() -> xreg.mat
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(xreg.mat))) -> fit # SUCCESS!!
fit %>% pull(arima) %>% pluck(1, 'fit', 'par')
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
# term       estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 xreg.matx1  -0.491      0.821   -0.598    0.561
# 2 xreg.matx2  -0.0713     0.821   -0.0869   0.932

# syms vector, unspliced with `!!!`?
# succeeds, _seems_ like this might be the tidy way
# but I barely understand what I did
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-idx, -y) %>% colnames() %>% syms() -> xreg.syms
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~xreg(!!!xreg.syms))) -> fit # SUCCESS!!??
fit %>% pull(arima) %>% pluck(1, 'fit', 'par')
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1     -0.491      0.821   -0.598    0.561
# 2 x2     -0.0713     0.821   -0.0869   0.932


Could you please add the packages you are using to your question? Could you subset your data to just the y and x variables and then use the expression y ~ .? Something like dat %>% select(y, starts_with("x")) %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y ~ .)).

@LMc Thanks, I just added packages to my code. Also, I tried you suggestion with .. It didn't work for me.
